# CReateProcess() API causing Unhandled exception. C++ std:: alternative API for CreateProcess

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, createprocess

I've a Vc++ code an A.EXE project (MBCS) and a static library project (Unicode). The static library (*.lib) project has the code like below which tries to launch a different exe (pwrtest.exe for example) from within it. BUt the code is crashing when the CReateProcess() statement is executed.

> Error is  "Unhandled Eception at  (ntdll.dll) in "A.EXE":
>   ::Access Vioaltion reading location 0xCCCCCCCC

I made sure that the values in appPath & workdir are correct.
They are values like this ::
c:\Users\abcd\xyz\somedirectory\abc etc...
with directory names separated by double slashes "\".

I really don't understand what is the problem.

Also I've put a try catch statement but when I step in to code (F10) on the line CreateProcess() it immidiately crashes and throws exception as above. 
So it's not even coming to catch statement.

**As Create process() is a C API & C types are always prone to memory elaks etc.. , just wondering if there is a C++ STD:: library counterpart (some container function API) which is much simpler but doing the job of CreateProcess() C API.**

```
 PROCESS_INFORMATION pI;
    STARTUPINFO         sI;
    LPTSTR              appPath;
    LPTSTR              workDir;

    wchar_t cwd[_MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectory(_MAX_PATH, cwd);
    wchar_t TestEXEPath[_MAX_PATH];
    wcscpy(TestEXEPath, cwd);

    wcscat(TestEXEPath, L"\\somedircetory\\abc\\pwrtest.exe /sleep /c:1");

    appPath = TestEXEPath;
    wchar_t workDirForTestEXE[_MAX_PATH];
    wcscpy(workDirForTestEXE, cwd);
    wcscat(workDirForTestEXE, L"\\somedirectory\\abc");
    workDir = workDirForTestEXE;

    try
    {
        if (!CreateProcess(NULL, appPath, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, workDir, &sI, &pI))
        {
            ......
        }
        {
            ......
        }
    }
    catch (exception& exType)
    {
        std::cout << "ExType is" << exType.what() << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `sI` is uninitialized, and it's an input parameter.  When `CreateProcess` reads from it, all sorts of bad things can happen.  Several of the members are defined as pointers to strings.  Reading from an invalid pointer is not a C++ exception, which is why your `catch` statement didn't handle it.

The fix is quite simple, change

```
STARTUPINFO sI;
```

to

```
STARTUPINFO sI = {sizeof sI};
```

There's no function in the standard C++ library half as powerful as the OS-specific `CreateProcess`.  You're using the ability of `CreateProcess` to control the initial working directory, something that `system`, `spawn`, and `exec` can't do.  (`fork` + `cwd` + `exec` can, but that's a very bad way to do things on Windows)

Comment: THank you. It fixed the crash issue. But just curious to know this statement "STARTUPINFO sI = {sizeof sI};". STARTUPINFO is a structure. 
By doing {sizeof si}, how are we initializing the structure object here ?

Comment: @codeLover: The first item in the structure, `cbSize`, is set to `sizeof sI`.  The rest are set to zero.  "If there are fewer initializers in the list than members of the structure, the trailing members are initialized with 0."

Comment: THanks. So since the first member in this structure is the size of the structure this statement "{sizeof <structure_var>} worked fine. SO in order to initialize any such structure the common method should be to initialize it with the value for it's 1st member right ? So the rest will get initialized with "0". (Provided we are not interested in initializing it's members with some specific values. 

Just curious to know, if we are initializing the structure variable sI here to all "0"s, then what is the reason that this is being passed as input parameter ?

Comment: @codeLover: This structure provides access to a lot of options?  Want to start the program minimized?  Do it here.  Want to redirect the output to a file?  Do it here.  The MSDN documentation for STARTUPINFO explains all the things you can control and what structure variable and flags need to be set to activate them.